# Copying formula to a range of cells and converting it to a value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the formula from D1 and paste it till last row(26446) value may increase

```
Dim lrow As Double
lrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   Range("D2").Copy Destination:=Range("D2:D" & lrow)
   Range("D2" & "lrow").Copy   'THIS LINE SHOWS 1004 error
   Range("D2:D" & "lrow").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

How to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already got two excellent answers and hence this is not an answer but an enhancement to your code.

1. You don't need to declare the row variable as `Double`. `Long`  is good enough. You may want to read up on Data type [HERE](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/standard-vba-data-types.html)
2. Your code can be reduced to this

**Code**

BTW, Your question says `D1` but your code is taking `D2` into consideration. So I am going with `D2`. If it is `D1` then replace `D2` by `D1` below.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim lrow As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("D2:D" & lrow).Formula = .Range("D2").Formula
        .Range("E2:E" & lrow).Formula = .Range("E2").Formula
        .Range("F2:F" & lrow).Formula = .Range("F2").Formula
        .Range("G2:G" & lrow).Formula = .Range("G2").Formula

        .Range("D2:G" & lrow).Value = .Range("D2:G" & lrow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you... I have 1 more issue.. I have 4 columns with different formulas. i need to copy them till the last row. I tried the above code for each column.But that takes too much time for execution.Is there any alternative way to optimize my code??

Comment: your the best :) :P i changed couple of things and adopted your suggestion. Wow 15 Min's optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Anything within quotes will be considered as a string so "lrow" is considered as a `String` and not a variable.

It should be

```
Range("D" & lrow).Copy
```

or whatever range you are trying to copy. I think, you are trying

```
Range("D2:D" & lrow).Copy
```

The other simple alternative to

```
Range("D2:D" & "lrow").Copy  
Range("D2:D" & "lrow").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

is

```
Range("D2:D" & lrow).Value = Range("D2:D" & lrow).Value
```

Comment: + 1 on .Value = .Value :)